# StackExchange OpenID login fails with page cannot be displayed on fresh Win8 install

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange-openid

Attempting to log into Stackoverflow in "Desktop Mode" on a fresh Win8 IE10 install with all default security settings causes this:

[image: Third party cookies appear to be disabled error message]

Attempting to log in manually causes a page cannot be found error

[image: OPENID Not Found page error]

Comment: I attempted to delete all browsing information from the General tab, and even attempted to Reset the browser from the Advanced tab. Neither corrected the issue.